# Sharepoint 2010: In external application nees to get all sites with write permission for logged in user

Tags: sharepoint-2010, wss

In my external application i need to find  all sites with write permission for logged in user.
I am using WSS.

Is there any web service available for this task?
Or can i send a Query and get the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the client object model (see this msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535231.aspx) to work with SharePoint for outside the system.

Answer (score 0):

use SharePoint webservices. They have a special `asmx` for permissions:

```
/_vti_bin/permissions.asmx
```

This Web service is used to obtain the permissions assigned to a list or site, add new permissions, and update or removing existing permissions.

Here's a blog post about using the permissions webservice:
[example](http://www.jamestsai.net/Blog/post/Understand-SharePoint-Permissions-Part-2-Check-SharePoint-usergroup-permissions-with-Permissions-web-service-and-JavaScript.aspx)